# Responsive centered 2x2 Grid in Angular Ionic

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, styling

The issue I'm running into is I can't get a 2 x 2 grid on the center of my screen. This is the code I have so far on the HTML. Just to clarify the project is being built for a native mobile application.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      Testing
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<app-navbar></app-navbar>

<ion-content color="primary">
  <ion-grid class="ion-justify-content-center">
    <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center">
      <ion-col>
        <div>
          1 of 4
        </div>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <div>
          2 of 4
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center">
      <ion-col>
        <div>
          3 of 4
        </div>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <div>
          4 of 4
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

It is stuck to the left side and when I remove the `ion-content` tag it goes centered up top but not in the middle of the screen where I'd like it to be. Any help would be appreciated.

[Rough Mockup of how I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxg27.png)

Comment: please upload Screen Shot, exactly what you want

Comment: Added the screenshot

Comment: check below answer with SS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add **page.scss**

```
ion-grid{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

https://prnt.sc/pn3ey9